# SQL Function can’t return an Array

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to create cross product function in SQL on Vertica using array as return value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION cross_product(a1 FLOAT, a2 FLOAT, a3 FLOAT, b1 FLOAT, b2 FLOAT, b3 FLOAT)
RETURN ARRAY[FLOAT]
AS BEGIN 
RETURN ARRAY[a2*b3 - a3*b2, a3*b1 - a1*b3, a1*b2 - a2*b1];
END;
```

But I get the following error:

```
Syntax error at or near “ARRAY”
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: `return float[]`?

Comment: Could not convert type array[float]  to float[]

Comment: Does a basic `SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3]` work? Arrays were introduced with Vertica 10.

Comment: Yes it does (also creating table with array type column works)

Comment: The documentation does not go into detail. But what it does certainly not explicitly mention, is *complex data types*, to which ARRAYs belong. So I would expect that arrays are not supported in SQL based function definitions. Check the docu on User Defined Extensions (UDx) in C++,  Python, R or Java, to see if you can get any further that way ...